# How to set VBox size to scene

Tags: java, javafx

I have a VBox as root in a scene, this VBox contains a MenuBar and a BorderPane.
What i would know is how to make automatic the resizing of everything (i guess  that only the vbox should be enough) when the window is resized widthout adding a changelistener to the scene.widthproperty property.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So why can't you add a ChangeListener?

Comment: because of the absence of a method in menubar and in borderpane that allows me to resize in automatic all the content, in that case i should resize every element of the childs of vbox, i only want to know if there is a particular method that is provided by javafx to do this.

Comment: child elements of menubar and borderpane have relative sizes yet

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this hack:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        //Get visible bounds of the screen
        Rectangle2D screenbounds=Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        VBox root=new VBox();
        //Set scene's size to maximum
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,screenbounds.getWidth(),screenbounds.getHeight());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        HBox one =new HBox(),two=new HBox();
        one.setPrefSize(400,500);
        two.setPrefSize(400,700);
        one.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE,null,null)));
        two.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKORANGE,null,null)));
        root.getChildren().addAll(one,two);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

It makes application window to use all available screen space. When you resize given window vertically, the boxes will shrink appropriately.

You still have to set preferred sizes of nodes to make resize 'automatic'.